# Monotouch - Ibtool does not exist in any folders referenced in the PATH environment variable

Tags: iphone, unix, xamarin.ios

I've just installed monotouch and having a problem with my first build of an unchanged IPhone template project.  The build is not finding Ibtool in any of the folders in the PATH environment variable.  I get the following message :

> Build failed. ApplicationName='ibtool', CommandLine=....

If I do a search for Ibtool, it is in folder /Developer/usr/bin, which is not referenced in the PATH environment variable.

My UNIX is very rusty - I've tried changing the PATH variable to add this path in the terminal window, but this does not persist.

Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you recently upgraded to Snow Leopard without downloading the Snow Leopard version of Xcode? I've seen that the Snow Leopard upgrade might leave Xcode alone and this error will start showing up.

Additionally, make sure you install Xcode and MonoTouch on the Boot partition.

Comment: No - I've installed Snow Leopard but not the Snow Leopard version of XCode.  I'm downloading that now, and I'll try the install - Thanks!

Comment: Note: make sure to install the **iPhone SDK** Xcode for Snow Leopard

Comment: Done that, and reinstalled mono and monotouch - SUCCESS!  Thanks very much Frank!

Comment: Haha, glad it worked for you. Th exact same thing happened to one of my coworkers.

Answer (score 0):

In Snow Leopard & XCode 3.2.1, ibtool is located at /Developer/usr/bin/ibtool, which normally isn't in your search path. You can specify the full path to run ibtool, or if you're calling it from a shell script or makefile, do something like:

```
IBTOOL=/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool
${IBTOOL} --strings-file MainMenu.strings --write MainMenu.nib ../English.lproj/MainMenu.nib
```